# Add item to UIView without blocking recognisers

Tags: swift, uiview, interface-builder

How do I add a UIButton, UIImage, UILabel etc. without blocking any function the widget behind is set to call?

For example, I may have a UIButton, and on top of it, a UIImage (which will be smaller than the button, you would still be able to see and tap the button). How do I make it so when the UIImage is tapped the button behind's function is triggered? Note: I don't want to programme the image to have the same function as the button, nor do I want to simply add an image to the button. I want it to be on top.

I'm using Swift 5, Xcode 10.2, and MacBook Pro.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have one main `UIView` which would include your `UIButton` as well as `UIImageView` and then I would just add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the main view to handle when view gets tapped.